# Pass parameters by checking some condition to apex controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, actionfunction

I am trying to pass parameters by checking some condition inside the Javascript controller. Here's what i am trying to do:-

```
    CreateDiscrepancy: function(component, event, helper) { 
    var EMIInputValue = component.find("InputEMI").get("v.value");
            var TenureInputValue = component.find("InputTenure").get("v.value");
            var DisbursementInputValue = component.find("InputDisbursment").get("v.value");
            var discrepancyactioncall = component.get("c.createDiscrepancy");
            var valuetest;
            /*action.setParams({
                "ndcid": component.get("v.recordId")
            });*/
            discrepancyactioncall.setParams({
                "ndcid": component.get("v.recordId"),
                "CreateDiscrepancyForEmi":component.get("v.CreateDiscrepancyForEmi")
            });

            discrepancyactioncall.setCallback(this, function(response){
                var state = response.getState();
                console.log('STATE '+state);
                if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                    var storeResponse = response.getReturnValue();
                    //console.log('RESULT::: '+JSON.deserialize(storeResponse));
                    component.set("v.NDCRecord",storeResponse);  
                }    
                if(state === 'ERROR')
                {
                    var storeError = response.getError(); 
                    console.log(storeError[0].message);
                }
                console.log('TenureInputValue:: '+TenureInputValue);
                console.log('DATAbase value '+storeResponse.LoanApp__r.LoanTenure__c);
                if(storeResponse.LoanApp__r.LoanTenure__c!=TenureInputValue){

//condition checking and passing the paramter
                    **discrepancyactioncall.setParams({
                        "CreateDiscrepancyForTenure":true
                    });**  
                }
```

Based on some condition in if i want to pass a parameter to apex controller which creates a record in database.But i came to know that action.setParams() cannot be written inside the callBack().

> What would be other way around to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Is it something, you want to call an Apex method again based on your condition by passing that param?

Comment: Yes i want to call Apex method which will take the parameter passed from JS and create record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below code. It should work, and also keep these methods in component helper controller instead of component controller.

```
CreateDiscrepancy: function(component, event, helper) {
    var discrepancyactioncall = component.get("c.createDiscrepancy");
    discrepancyactioncall.setParams({
        "CreateDiscrepancyForTenure": true
    });
    discrepancyactioncall.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        console.log('STATE ' + state);
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var storeResponse = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.NDCRecord", storeResponse);
            if (storeResponse.LoanApp__r.LoanTenure__c != TenureInputValue) {
                this.newMethodToCallApex(component, event, theParam);
            }
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(discrepancyactioncall);
},

newMethodToCallApex: function(component, event, yourParam) {
    var discrepancyactioncallNew = component.get("c.createDiscrepancy");
    discrepancyactioncallNew.setParams({
        "conditionalParam": yourParam
    });
    // Your Apex method Call
    $A.enqueueAction(discrepancyactioncallNew);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..It is showing me this.receivingParamter(component,event,valuetest); is not a function where valuetest is a variable storing true..

Comment: keep the new method in Helper controller and try below code
`helper.newMethod(component, event, theParam);`

Comment: Perhaps a better way to set createDiscrepancyForTenure in this case would be via valueChange event? Create a boolean attribute for createDiscrepancyForTenure and set it via CreateDiscrepancy method call. Then fire a secondary apex call when the newly created attribute value changes like so: <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.createDiscrepancyForTenure}" action="{!c. newMethodToCallApex}"/> This way the two methods are decoupled and you can be certain of updating the tenure when need be.

Comment: Can you help me with code guidance i am little new to lightning..